# How is a json file read? extjs

Tags: ajax, extjs, model

Say that I have a the fields here for a user in a "json" format:

```
{
    "users": [
       {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Ed Spencer",
           "email": "ed@sencha.com"
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Abe Elias",
           "email": "abe@sencha.com"
       }
    ]
}
```

I assume that the root here is "users". Would I save this text as a users.json file?

And from there, how do I read from this file (in this case, with ext.js)

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'email']
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
});
```

What is the url? Is it an absolute path? Will this even work??? Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an HTML page, a JavaScript file is served relative to the URL of the HTML page, or from an absolute path.

> Would I save this text as a users.json file?

You can, sure.

> What is the url?

The URL `users.json` is relative to the URL of the HTML page that is running your application, so if the HTML page was at `http://localhost/myapp/index.html`, the relative path `users.json` would be the same as the absolute path `http://localhost/myapp/users.json`

> Is it an absolute path?

No, `users.json` is a relative path. You *could* use an absolute path if you wanted to.

I would make a `data` folder inside your `app` folder and use `app/data/users.json` as the URL.

You should also learn Chrome Developer Tools so that you can see the network requests.

Comment: I did exactly this, but I keep getting a "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied" Error and am not sure why?

Comment: are you running on a server or via the file system? what does chrome developer tools network tab tell you?

Comment: Only on a file system, and I currently am not able to use chrome in my office

Comment: And extjs is soooo "cross-browser". Not. I can't even get my windows to show up in IE 9.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "users": [
       {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Ed Spencer",
           "email": "ed@sencha.com"
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Abe Elias",
           "email": "abe@sencha.com"
       }
    ]
}
```

in your model's field, there is no id, which comes from json, there is only name and email fields...

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'email']
});
```

add id field to model, like this

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
});
```